# Hibernate Not Deleting the orphan Child Entites

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am beginner in JPA/Hibernate so this code could be fundamentally wrong but i want to basically delete the keySkills by leveraging orphan Removal. I have tried the following ways, please guide me on what i am doing wrong

**Job Entity**

```
public class Job extends AuditableBaseObject implements Serializable {
    
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYER_ID")
      private Employer employer;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JsonIgnoreProperties("job")
      @Where(clause = "RETIRED=0")
      private List<JobAcceptableWorkStatus> jobAcceptWork;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JsonIgnoreProperties("job")
      @Where(clause = "RETIRED=0")
      private List<JobKeySkills> jobKeySkills;
    
      @Column(name = "TITLE")
      private String title;
    
      @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
      private String description;
    
      @Column(name = "MIN_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE")
      private int minYearsOfExperience;
    }
```

**KeySkills Entity**

```
public class JobKeySkills extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Job job;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_SKILL_ID")
  private ReferenceData keySkill;

  @Column(name = "SKILL_LEVEL")
  private String skillLevel;

  @Column(name = "SKILL_PRIORITY")
  private String skillPriority;
}
```

I am trying to delete the jobSkills by setting

```
job.setRetired(false);
job.setKeySkills(null);
jobRepository.save(job);
```

And also tried

```
jobkeySkillsToBeAdded.setRetired(false);
jobkeySkillsToBeAdded.setJob(null);
jobKeySkillsRepository.save(jobkeySkillsToBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the cascade type to @OneToMany annotations in `Job`  as follows:

```java
public class Job extends AuditableBaseObject implements Serializable {
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYER_ID")
    private Employer employer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, 
               orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("job")
    @Where(clause = "RETIRED=0")
    private List<JobAcceptableWorkStatus> jobAcceptWork;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, 
               orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("job")
    @Where(clause = "RETIRED=0")
    private List<JobKeySkills> jobKeySkills;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "MIN_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE")
    private int minYearsOfExperience;
}
```

Comment: But what has orphan Removal to do with cascading since orphan removal should happen when there is no relationship between parent and child entities which i am trying to do by setting the value as null.

Comment: At least `CascadeType.PERSIST` should be present.